# Copy activity - Excel ordinary mapping issue with Range

Tags: copy, mapping, azure-data-factory

The combination of explicit ordinary mapping and Range parameter does not work as expected in Copy activity.

The Source

- excel file :

[image]

- DataSet :

  [image]

The Sink - SQL table :

[image]

Issue:

When I choose the Range in Source dataset for example B1, the mapping works incorrectly.

I expect

| Excel Col | Dataset ordinary |
| --- | --- |
| B | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 3 |

But ADF do not change starting column, moreover it trims the last column from mapping:

| Excel Col | Dataset ordinary |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

So if I put B1 to Range parameter I only can access A,B,C columns. If I tried to access 4th column I will receive an error.

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]

Case with same Range but trying add 4th column to mapping:

[image]

[image]

I expect that ordinary numbers do take into account the Range attribute (so if you put F2 it will start to count from F column). Also, I am a bit concerned about why it trims the columns from the right side of the table.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> ErrorCode=ExcelInvalidColumnIndex,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Invalid column index '3' is specified while read data from worksheet 'Sheet1'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'..

This error happens when schemas are not imported in mapping after changing the range of excel dataset. Whenever the source dataset is changed(here range of excel sheet is changed), it is essential to **Import projection** in mapping tab.

- When you want to give Range as a dynamic content like `@dataset().Range`, then do not give manual mapping. ADF will detect schema of source and map with sink automatically while running the pipeline.
- Click the mapping tab of copy activity.
- Click **clear** to clear the manual mapping which is done earlier.

[image]

Comment: So if I use dynamic range I can not use dynamic mapping?

Comment: You can use dynamic mapping. But  manual mapping does not work as expected.

Comment: I've just tied enter to mapping: @json('
{"type": "TabularTranslator", "mappings": [
{"source": { "ordinal": "1" },"sink": { "name": "var1" }},
{"source": { "ordinal": "2" },"sink": { "name": "var2" }},
{"source": { "ordinal": "3" },"sink": { "name": "var3" }}
]}
')
with Range: B2

The pipeline was successful, but the results are wrong: data from columns: A,B,C was copied to SQL table

Comment: If you don't give mapping, does it work?

Comment: no it does not - because the names of columns in SQL are different ( var1, var2 ...). But this is not the case. I need to have the ability to use dynamic range + dynamic mapping.

Comment: Where can I find the documentation with the limitations that you mentioned ( like for manual mapping etc)?